# Double split a string and add it to JTable

Tags: java, swing, split, jtable

I have a Jtable Table in my gui and a java method that returns a string like this : name1#surname1#job1$name2#surname2#job2 etc . I don't know the exact length of the string as it was created depending on how many people have in my database. I want to split this string and add it to a JTable , every value under the right category ! But I can't achive that .

Here's the code for my JTable :

```
table = new JTable();
    table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {
            {null, null, null},
            {null, null, null},
            {null, null, null},
            {null, null, null},
            {null, null, null},
            {null, null, null},
            {null, null, null},
            {null, null, null},
            {null, null, null},
            {null, null, null},
    }, new String[] {
            "Name", "Surname", "Job"}) {
        Class[] columnTypes = new Class[] { String.class, String.class,
                String.class};

        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return columnTypes[columnIndex];
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot split with **$** character. There are some characters in the Pattern class that are not allowed for splitting.

Comment: Ok this is a minor problem , as I can change this character to #(again) or to space for example ! The problem is how can I split the string and to add in the right column, the right values

Comment: '$' is a special character in regular expressions that checks if a line end follows. If you want to split a string using this character, you must escape it using the string "\\$" as showin in peeskillet's example.  This is true for ALL special characters. (i.e. '.'). The key thing to remember is that the `String.split()` takes a String argument that is used as a regular expression, not as a String literal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Don't set null values for the model. No point. Just do this

   ```
   String[] colNames = {"name", "surname","job"};
   DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(colNames, 0):
   JTable table = new JTable(model);
   ```
2. Then split the String into an array by the $

   ```
   String[] lines = longString.split("\\$");
   ```
3. Just loop through that array and split again and add the array from the second split to the `model`

   ```
   for (String line : lines) {
       model.addRow(line.split("#");
   }
   ```

That's all there really is to it :)

Run this test

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestTable5 {

    public TestTable5() {
        String blah = "pee#skillet#assassin$pee#skillet#stackoverflow";
        String[] colNames = {"name", "surname", "job"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(colNames, 0);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        String[] lines = blah.split("\\$");   // escape the $
        for (String line : lines) {
            model.addRow(line.split("#"));
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestTable5();
            }
        });
    }
}
```